# Call an outstream bluetooth method from another class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arduino

I have a color picker palette class and i want to send the color information while the client changes the color ( OnTouch ) through the bluetooth class in separate java file. The bluetooth Fragment is working and connecting perfectly . The problem is that the write method is working in its class but when i initialize it and try to use it in the color palette class it crashes on the test.
The working write() method in the bluetooth class :

```
private int col;
public void write(int color) {
    col=color;
    if(socket.isConnected()) {

       // data = "r " + Color.red(color) + "/n" + "g " + Color.green(color) + "/n" + "b " + Color.blue(color) + "/n";

        try {


       /* byte[] dataToSend = {(byte) r,(byte)Color.red(color),(byte)Color.green(color),(byte) Color.blue(color), 0x0A};
        //remove spurious line endings from color bytes so the serial device doesn't get confused
        for (int i=0; i<dataToSend.length-1; i++){
            if (dataToSend[i] == 0x0A){
                dataToSend[i] = 0x0B;
            }
        }*/
           // mmOutStream.write(data.getBytes());
            mmOutStream.write(("r " + Color.red(col) + '\n').getBytes());
            mmOutStream.write(("g " + Color.green(col) + '\n').getBytes());
            mmOutStream.write(("b " + Color.blue(col) + '\n').getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                String.format("Not connected."),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The way i am trying to use the method in the color palette class(ColorPicker.java) :

```
 BluetoothFragment rat = new BluetoothFragment();
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();
        int cx = x - getWidth() / 2;
        int cy = y - getHeight() / 2;
        double d = Math.sqrt(cx * cx + cy * cy);

        if (d <= colorWheelRadius) {

            colorHSV[0] = (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(cy, cx)) + 180f);
            colorHSV[1] = Math.max(0f, Math.min(1f, (float) (d / colorWheelRadius)));

            invalidate();

        } else if (x >= getWidth() / 2 && d >= innerWheelRadius) {

            colorHSV[2] = (float) Math.max(0, Math.min(1, Math.atan2(cy, cx) / Math.PI + 0.5f));

            invalidate();
        }

        return true;
    }
    rat.write(getColor());
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: it crashes with an exception? please edit your question and post the error message and stacktrace.

Comment: I am testing the app on my phone and it crashes in the moment i touch the color picker "app stopped". When i remove the method from ColorPicker.java i can use the palette but its useless when no data is sent throught the bluetooth . The only thing i saw in Android Studio is this:http://prntscr.com/8osw2s